# Setting Media Query for iPad Air and iPad Pro

Tags: html, css, next.js, ipad, responsive-design

I am stuck in setting the media query for different iPad devices. In my next Js code, I have created three cards (or divs) equally divided in a row ([react-bootstrap grid system used for it](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/layout/grid)). The cards can take up the whole width by default as a part of the grid system but I would like to limit their width to specific pixels.
For this, I am trying to set the width to a card class `.post-card-main-wrapper` using CSS media queries.
This is what I have done so far (adding only required codebase) :

CSS:

```
/* Default styles for all devices */
.post-card-main-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
}

/* Styles for iPad Pro */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .post-card-main-wrapper {
    width: 400px;
  }
}

/* Styles for iPad Air */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .post-card-main-wrapper {
    width: 220px;
    height: 350px;
  }
}

/* Styles for smaller screens (e.g., iPhone) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .post-card-main-wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
  }
}

/* Styles for the smallest screens (e.g., iPhone SE) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .post-card-main-wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="featured-articles-container row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-12">
        <div class="featured-posts">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-sm col-12">
                        <div class="ant-divider css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8 ant-divider-horizontal ant-divider-with-text ant-divider-with-text-left ant-divider-no-default-orientation-margin-left" role="separator">
                            <span class="ant-divider-inner-text" style="margin-left:100px">
                                <h2>Featured Posts</h2>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="justify-content-center row">
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm col-10">
                        <div class="post-card-main-wrapper">
                            <div class="post-card-img-wrapper"><img src="https://yuma.sharkthemes.com/blog-one/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2022/01/hand-person-girl-woman-hair-photography-78292-pxhere.com_-600x800.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
                            <div class="post-card-content-wrapper" style="background:white">
                                <span class="ant-typography css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8">PHOTOGRAPHY, PORTRAIT</span>
                                <h3>Some Article Title Here</h3>
                                <span class="ant-typography css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8">December 2, 2022</span>
                                <div class="ant-typography ant-typography-ellipsis ant-typography-ellipsis-multiple-line css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8" style="font-size: 16px; margin-top: 1em; -webkit-line-clamp: 4;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm col-10">
                        <div class="post-card-main-wrapper">
                            <div class="post-card-img-wrapper"><img src="https://yuma.sharkthemes.com/blog-one/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2022/01/hand-person-girl-woman-hair-photography-78292-pxhere.com_-600x800.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
                            <div class="post-card-content-wrapper" style="background:white">
                                <span class="ant-typography css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8">PHOTOGRAPHY, PORTRAIT</span>
                                <h3>Some Article Title Here</h3>
                                <span class="ant-typography css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8">December 2, 2022</span>
                                <div class="ant-typography ant-typography-ellipsis ant-typography-ellipsis-multiple-line css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8" style="font-size: 16px; margin-top: 1em; -webkit-line-clamp: 4;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm col-10">
                        <div class="post-card-main-wrapper">
                            <div class="post-card-img-wrapper"><img src="https://yuma.sharkthemes.com/blog-one/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2022/01/hand-person-girl-woman-hair-photography-78292-pxhere.com_-600x800.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
                            <div class="post-card-content-wrapper" style="background:white">
                                <span class="ant-typography css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8">PHOTOGRAPHY, PORTRAIT</span>
                                <h3>Some Article Title Here</h3>
                                <span class="ant-typography css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8">December 2, 2022</span>
                                <div class="ant-typography ant-typography-ellipsis ant-typography-ellipsis-multiple-line css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8" style="font-size: 16px; margin-top: 1em; -webkit-line-clamp: 4;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Adding the main desktop view (using iPad Air for development) screenshot as well:

[image: Desktop Design]

Now the issue is that when I try to set the specific width of the cards to equally spaced
columns (or grid) for one device, it messes up the width for another device. Most of the time, it's a battle between **iPad Air** and **iPad Pro**.

**Query used for iPad Air**, looks good with proper spacing and width for the cards. And even though I have tried to use a **separate query for iPad Pro**, it always picks the query meant for iPad Air, and the cards look completely squeezed together without any space.

Adding more screenshots for reference:

[image: iPad Pro]
[image: iPad Air]
[image: iPad Mini]
[image: Nest Hub]

I am unable to figure out the proper approach to fix this for iPad as well as other not-so-common (real-life) devices. Any help and solution to use proper media queries for all current devices in Google Chrome's dimensions and if there are any rules to follow while specifying the responsive CSS would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you setting widths at all? The grid system should take care of this. 

The problem itself can be seen in your first screenshot. You're setting a width of 400px for all 3 elements for a screen width >= 1024px. 3x400 = 1200px.

Comment: @fabian-mcfly The reason why I am setting 400 px for 3 elements is that otherwise, it is taking up all of the default grid widths. I don't want that. I need to set a specific width for these elements despite being inside a single grid

Comment: If you don't want to use the whole column width, forcing the contents to be wider than the column itself isn't exactly helping. Use max-width instead of width or use a relative width (for example 90%).

Answer (score 2):

How about setting `.post-card-main-wrapper { max-width:100%; }`?
With your permission, I did not fix the html, but only removed your media requests in the css, reducing the code to two lines:

```css
.post-card-main-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  width: min(400px, 100%);
  /* width: 400px; */
  /* max-width: 100%; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  crossorigin="anonymous">
  
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
          <div class="ant-divider css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8 ant-divider-horizontal ant-divider-with-text ant-divider-with-text-left ant-divider-no-default-orientation-margin-left" role="separator">
              <span class="ant-divider-inner-text" style="margin-left:100px">
                  <h2>Featured Posts</h2>
              </span>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="justify-content-center row">
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4">
          <div class="post-card-main-wrapper">
              <div class="post-card-img-wrapper"><img src="https://yuma.sharkthemes.com/blog-one/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2022/01/hand-person-girl-woman-hair-photography-78292-pxhere.com_-600x800.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
              <div class="post-card-content-wrapper" style="background:white">
                  <span class="ant-typography css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8">PHOTOGRAPHY, PORTRAIT</span>
                  <h3>Some Article Title Here</h3>
                  <span class="ant-typography css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8">December 2, 2022</span>
                  <div class="ant-typography ant-typography-ellipsis ant-typography-ellipsis-multiple-line css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8" style="font-size: 16px; margin-top: 1em; -webkit-line-clamp: 4;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4">
          <div class="post-card-main-wrapper">
              <div class="post-card-img-wrapper"><img src="https://yuma.sharkthemes.com/blog-one/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2022/01/hand-person-girl-woman-hair-photography-78292-pxhere.com_-600x800.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
              <div class="post-card-content-wrapper" style="background:white">
                  <span class="ant-typography css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8">PHOTOGRAPHY, PORTRAIT</span>
                  <h3>Some Article Title Here</h3>
                  <span class="ant-typography css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8">December 2, 2022</span>
                  <div class="ant-typography ant-typography-ellipsis ant-typography-ellipsis-multiple-line css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8" style="font-size: 16px; margin-top: 1em; -webkit-line-clamp: 4;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4">
          <div class="post-card-main-wrapper">
              <div class="post-card-img-wrapper"><img src="https://yuma.sharkthemes.com/blog-one/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2022/01/hand-person-girl-woman-hair-photography-78292-pxhere.com_-600x800.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
              <div class="post-card-content-wrapper" style="background:white">
                  <span class="ant-typography css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8">PHOTOGRAPHY, PORTRAIT</span>
                  <h3>Some Article Title Here</h3>
                  <span class="ant-typography css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8">December 2, 2022</span>
                  <div class="ant-typography ant-typography-ellipsis ant-typography-ellipsis-multiple-line css-dev-only-do-not-override-1i536d8" style="font-size: 16px; margin-top: 1em; -webkit-line-clamp: 4;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you the mere idea so that you can code yourself.

Please see the css of the container-fluid class. If the display property of container-fluid is flex, then this three columns will appear irrespective of the screen size.

Or if the display property of col-xl-4.col-md-4 class is inline-block, and width has been mentioned to some percentage between 25% to 33% and each if each col-xl-4.col-md-4 class is given float:left,then this will happen. This practice was used before the advent of the media screen property.

Also don't mention height so that height will be scaled automatically. And if you mention specific width, the size of the image remains same between two consecutive width-range in devices. So, you can mention a min-width to accommodate smaller devices. Apart from this, you should mention an actual width varying from 80% to 100% according to your requirement.

```
@media only screen and (/* min width */) and (/* max-width */){

  container-fluid{display:block
  }
.col-xl-4.col-md-4{
   display : block !important;
   float:none !important;
   min-width: 300px; /*Change according to your requirement */
   width : 90%; /*Change according to your requirement */
   height:auto;
   margin : 0 auto;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you switch to flexbox (sometimes called flex).  The latest version of Bootstrap actually uses flex under the covers, but if you want to learn how to use it yourself and eventually just leverage Bootstrap's flex wrappers here's a good tutorial:

https://matthewjamestaylor.com/3-column-layouts#responsive-3-column